# Bottom Sheet does not EXPANDED or COLLAPSED

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have created very simple `Bottom Sheet` at my tested project flowing this [page](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031) .First i created my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Bottom Sheets"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In MainActivity i've written these codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

        Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_1:
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run app on emulator `BottomSheetBehavior` is `EXPANDED`!!!When i changed my code to this:

```
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_1:
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        break;
```

And press btn_1 `BottomSheetBehavior` does not collapsed? What is the problem?
This is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to Add this two lines in your bottom sheet layout file

```
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

layout_behavior - to apply the bottom sheet collapse and expand behavior to up and down the layout
peekHeight - the height of layout you want to show initial when an activity launch , you can change it according to view height

if this is already added then can you please share your main activity xml file where you have include the bottom sheet layout

Comment: Thanks dude I add `android:orientation="vertical"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` and worked well.